# Apache POI - reorder rows

Tags: apache-poi

I'm trying to solve the problem, to swap the rows in an excel sheet without breaking the formulas referring to these rows.

Example:

```
Sheet1: rows 1,2,3,4
```

The rows need to be reordered as follows

```
Sheet1: rows 4,3,2,1
```

I've tried by POI shift method, but I'm unable to achieve my goal.

Any guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about it for several days and I read that there is a bug with XSSF objects, giving problems when you insert in row 0 when reordering, so I have implemented it manually:

```
private static void reverseRows(XSSFWorkbook workbook, Integer sheetIndex) {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
    Sheet newSheet = workbook.createSheet(sheet.getSheetName()+"AUX");

    Integer numberOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i ++) {
        copyRow(workbook,workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet),workbook.getSheetIndex(newSheet),numberOfRows - 1 - i,i);
    }       
    String oldName = sheet.getSheetName();
    workbook.removeSheetAt(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet));
    workbook.cloneSheet(workbook.getSheetIndex(newSheet), oldName);
    workbook.removeSheetAt(workbook.getSheetIndex(newSheet));
    workbook.setSheetOrder(oldName, sheetIndex);
    workbook.setActiveSheet(0);
}

private static void copyRow(XSSFWorkbook workbook,Integer srcSheetIndex, Integer destSheetIndex, Integer srcRowIndex,Integer destRowIndex) {
    XSSFSheet srcSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(srcSheetIndex);
    XSSFRow srcRow = srcSheet.getRow(srcRowIndex);

    XSSFSheet destSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(destSheetIndex);
    XSSFRow destRowAux = destSheet.createRow(destRowIndex + 1); 
    destRowAux.copyRowFrom(srcRow, new CellCopyPolicy());
      
    XSSFRow destRow = destSheet.createRow(destRowIndex);
    destRow.copyRowFrom(destRowAux, new CellCopyPolicy());
    destSheet.removeRow(destRowAux);
}
```

The code is simple to debug it to analyze it, it would be necessary to include in the policy of copying cells for formulas and others.